# Obter linhas únicas no banco de dados, mysql

Tags: mysql

É necessário obter as linhas que não *possuem duplicatas em uma tabela,* fiz pesquisas e encontrei a função `DISTINCT` porém essa não resolve o problema, pois ela de certa forma agrupa os dados.

Uma forma de resolver seria recorrendo ao PHP e verificando uma a uma, mas antes de recair para essa opção quero ter certeza que não tenho outras mais eficientes.

Um exemplo:

```
+----------+------+
| Customer | Pets |
+----------+------+
|       20 |    2 |
|       21 |    3 |
|       22 |    3 |
|       23 |    2 |
|       24 |    4 |
|       25 |    8 |
+----------+------+
```

o retorno teria que ser **4, 8** pois elas são únicas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você quer todos os pets com uma única entrada na sua tabela. A tradução literal disso em SQL, assumindo que o nome da sua tabela é `CUSTOMER_PET` seria:

```
SELECT pets FROM customer_pet GROUP BY pets HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Caso você queira as outras colunas isso você pode ser feito com uma *subquery*:

```
SELECT
  customer,
  pets
FROM customer_pet
WHERE pets IN (
  SELECT pets
  FROM customer_pet
  GROUP BY pets
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

De fato, como a query mais interna garante que teremos apenas uma linha por cada pet alternativamente podemos eliminar a *subquery* e usar uma função agregadora que retorne o resultado (e.g., `MIN` ou `MAX`):

```
SELECT
  MIN(customer) AS customer,
  pets
FROM customer_pet
GROUP BY pets
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```